# java.library.path not honored with maven-shade-plugin

Tags: java, maven, java-native-interface, hbase, snappy

If I have code like this:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
LoadIncrementalHFiles lihf;
lihf = new LoadIncrementalHFiles(conf);
lihf.doBulkLoad(/*proper args*/)
```

This works fine with -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native/ in the command line. The table is Snappy compressed

I need a uber-jar and hence use maven-shade-plugin to create it.

Now the same code doesn't work even if I specify -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native/ in the command line

The error is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader.buildSupportsSnappy()Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles.groupOrSplitPhase(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:382)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles.doBulkLoad(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:258)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader.buildSupportsSnappy()Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader.buildSupportsSnappy(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec.checkNativeCodeLoaded(SnappyCodec.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec.getDecompressorType(SnappyCodec.java:185)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool.getDecompressor(CodecPool.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.Compression$Algorithm.getDecompressor(Compression.java:331)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileBlock$AbstractFSReader.decompress(HFileBlock.java:1457)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileBlock$FSReaderV2.readBlockDataInternal(HFileBlock.java:1963)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileBlock$FSReaderV2.readBlockData(HFileBlock.java:1703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileBlock$AbstractFSReader$1.nextBlock(HFileBlock.java:1350)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileBlock$AbstractFSReader$1.nextBlockWithBlockType(HFileBlock.java:1358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileReaderV2.<init>(HFileReaderV2.java:127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFile.pickReaderVersion(HFile.java:552)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFile.createReaderWithEncoding(HFile.java:589)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFile.createReader(HFile.java:636)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles.groupOrSplit(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:440)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles$2.call(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:361)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles$2.call(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:359)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a classpath issue.

old command to run (which failed):

```
java -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native -cp jarname.jar:`hbase classpath` com.className
```

new command to run (which succeeds):

```
java -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native -cp `hbase classpath`:jarname.jar com.className
```